# How to put an image in html coding

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBac0.jpg)How do I put an image in html? I have tried copying and pasting, dragging and dropping, everything. I just don't know how to get a url for it. That's the question.

[image of blog header type thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTxPU.jpg)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Comment: Create a directory: c:\www. Save the file with the name index.html to that directory. Drag and Drop the image to c:\www. Open up the html file in notepad and under the body tag type <img src="imagename.jpg" />. Open up Explorer and in the address bar type C:/www. You should see the image in the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic html image tag concept:

## Tag

```
<img src="IMAGE_SOURCE" alt="ALTER_NAME" />
```

## Example

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTxPU.jpg" alt="header_image" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ycrdqooc/

To know more details : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Comment: This is the correct answer.  You should mark it as correct by clicking the green checkmark @rsokoll .